# Пишем куку , при клике увеличиваем значение

Tags: javascript, cookie

Не могу понять в чем дело, не пишет куки при заходе на сайт, так же кликаю по елементу тоже не чего не происходит, подскажите где допустил ошибку

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Если установлены cookie то читаем их и сохраняем значение в переменную, если не установлены то значение переменной = 0
  var nCount = $.cookie('user_count') != undefined ? parseInt($.cookie('user_count')) : 0;
  //Отображаем значение на странице
  $('#counter').html(nCount);

  //Клик по элементу
  $('#topBtnClick').click(function() {
    //Увеличиваем счетчик на единицу
    nCount++;
    //Записываем значение в cookie
    $.cookie('user_count', nCount, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    //Отображаем значение на странице
    $('#counter').html(nCount);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: ваш плагин устарел  используйте новый 2.1.4 вот ссылка https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: на сайте используют новый

Comment: в новой версии плагина cookie устанавливаются  не так $.cookie('user_count') а так  Cookies.set('name', 'value'); вы используете старый функции потому и ошибки

Comment: поменял, не срабатывает=(

Comment: и последовательность скриптов должен быть так сначала jquery потом cookie потом ваш скрипт и это проверьте .

Comment: не понял=((( помогите пожалуйста=((

Comment: скрипты должны быть установлены одним за другим так как я написал наверху.для наглядности  покажу                                                                             <script src="jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script><!-- Jquery  -->
<script src="js.cookie.js" ></script><!-- Ваш cookie   -->
<script src="script.js"></script><!-- Скрипт который вы написали   -->

Comment: но у меня проблема, скрипт я вешаю с помощью GTM